# Is it "leave them to me" or "leave them with me"?

Tags: meaning, difference, idiomatic-language

> 1. Leave your children with me, I know how to babysit.
> 2. Leave your children to me, I know how to babysit.

Which one of these sentences are grammatical? I am thinking that they are both pretty much the same, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave your children **with** me is literally just telling someone to leave their children with you, but if let's say they misbehave, someone may say leave them **to** me, I can handle them. It means don't worry or I have this taken care of.